# Android image background repeat

Tags: android, background-image, repeat

I have a image used for a LinearLayout background 
Let's say image has 20x100 px
I want to make the image repeat only on x axes ... something like this in css

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

The LinearLayout is kinda big (1024 x 680 px) so my image will cover the entire width but only in the top (the rest of 580 px of height will be transparent)
I hope i was clear
Thanks

Comment: do u aware of draw9patch images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the android:background as a 9patch image to automatically stretch.

[9patch on Android Dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: This is not the answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 55):

try using [android:tileMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android%3atileMode)

create `background.xml` in drawable folder as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/bg" 
  android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and then use it in your layout xml as:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Not working, There isn't `android:tileMode` for `LinearLayout`